# How can I implement grouping preference in antlr?

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr

I want to write a lexer and parser which could take expressions like

```
(4+y)*8
4+5*x
(3)+(z*(4+w))*6
```

And then parse them considering the priority of multiplication over addition. In particular, I can't figure out how I could avoid

```
4+5*x
```

being grouped as

```
MULTIPLICATION(ADDITION(4,5),5) instead of ADDITION(4+MULTIPLICATION)
```

My lexer looks like that:

```
PLUS     : '+';
TIMES    : '*';
NUMBER   : [0-9]+'.'?[0-9]*;
VARIABLE : [(a-z)|(A-Z)]+;
OPENING  : '(';
CLOSING  : ')';
WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: `[(a-z)|(A-Z)]+` matches `'('`, `')'` and `'|'` too. You probably want `[a-zA-Z]+` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct grouping will happen automatically if you define your lower-priority operations closer to your "root expression" rule than the higher-priority ones:

```
expr
:       e=multDivExpr
    (   PLUS e=multDivExpr
    |   MINUS e=multDivExpr
    )*
;

multDivExpr
:       e=atomExpr 
    (   TIMES e=atom
    |   DIV e=atom
    |   REM e=atom
    )*
; 

atom
:       NUMBER
    |   VARIABLE
    |   OPENING e=expr CLOSING
;
```

A simple way to understand what's going on is to think that the recursive descent parser generated by ANTLR will use `multDivExpr` non-terminals as "building blocks" for the "additive" `expr` non-terminal, therefore applying the grouping to multiplication and division before considering addition and subtraction.

Comment: I get it now. Take it apart ot the smallest chunk. Makes sense. thank you.